# django error: The value of 'ordering[0]' refers to 'username', which is not an attribute of 'accounts.clinic_staff'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I extended my accounts custom user model using a one-to-one field and it worked fine. But when I tried customizing it to display more info such as the staff_number and location, the following error is returned:

<class 'accounts.admin.staffAdmin'>: (admin.E033) The value of 'ordering[0]' refers to 'username', which is not an attribute of 'accounts.clinic_staff'.

the staffAdmin class doesn't have username listed as a list_display and the clinic_staff is just returning the username. I'm stuck on what to do?

this is my accounts>models.py code:

```
from datetime import date
import email
import imp
from pyexpat import model
from tkinter import CASCADE
from tkinter.tix import Tree
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager


class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, password=None,):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Email address is required')
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Username is required')
        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username = username,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using = self.db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            password = password,
            username = username,
            )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using = self.db)
        return user

class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email   = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    #is_clinic_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    #staff_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)  #note for self - these fields are required

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username',]

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
    
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin # note to self - required
    
    def has_module_perms(self, app_Label):
        return True 

class clinic_staff(models.Model):
    staff = models.OneToOneField(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    location = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    staff_number = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.staff.username
```

my accounts admin.py code

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import clinic_staff
from accounts.models import Account
from accounts.models import clinic_staff
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

class AccountAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ('email', 'username', 'date_joined', 'last_login', 'is_admin', 'is_staff')
    search_field = ('email', 'username',)
    readonly_field = ('date_joined', 'last_login')
    filter_horizontal = ()
    list_filter = ()
    fieldsets = () # note to self: required field

class staffAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ('location', 'staff_number')
    search_field = ('location', 'staff_number')
    filter_horizontal = ()
    list_filter = ()
    fieldsets = ()

admin.site.register(Account, AccountAdmin)
admin.site.register(clinic_staff, staffAdmin)
```

Comment: hello did you do your migrations ?

Comment: I tried to but it wont let me migrate. giving the same error

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved it by:

Add ordering attribute in the admin.py like:

```
class staffAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ('location', 'staff_number')
    search_field = ('location', 'staff_number')
    filter_horizontal = ()
    list_filter = ()
    fieldsets = ()
    **ordering = ('username',)**
```

Comment: Your answer fixed my problem but I think you need to edit assignment line of "ordering" variable. You can remove asterisks and add a comment afterwards. This is more safe and you can still mark the point you want to draw attention to.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

**My django ver**: 4.2

**Solution**:
As per django docs, the solution is simple. Just add an ordering field too.

Link:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from .models import CustomUser

@admin.register(CustomUser)
class CustomUserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    list_display = ["email", "is_staff"]
    ordering = ["email"]
```

Answer (score -1):

ok i see

if you're not in production try to  delete your database

and run

manage.py makemigrations
manage.py  migrate

Comment: ok I did that and now it gives the following error: type object 'clinic_staff' has no attribute 'USERNAME_FIELD'

Comment: is it the migration wich give this error?

Comment: no the migrations worked but when i try to log into the website that shows up.